# Which separating method is cleaner for long function?

Tags: performance, conceptual

I have long of code function about 100 lines. It's hard to read.

Which is cleaner or better way to separate the function?

First way

```
function main() {
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    func4();
    func5();
}
```

Second way

```
function main() {
    // more code here
    func1();
}

function func1() {
    // more code here
    func2();
}

function func2() {
    // more code here
    func3();
}

function func3() {
    // more code here
    func4();
}
```

If no one better, when I should use second way instead of first way?

Comment: I'd go for the first one, but this question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `func1` should only call `func2` if that is part of what `func1` shall do.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you give me example? Right now I prefer first way, but my coworker second way.

Comment: If what `func2` does is necessary to do the task of `func1`, then it is appropriate to call `func2` from `func1`. If calling `func2` from `func1` serves only to hide its call from `main`, to keep that shorter, that's not a good reason to call it from `func1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good thing that you are bothering about this. It's always good to keep functions dedicated to a single conceptual purpose, and reasonably short.

The body of a function is structured as either:

- A sequence of actions.
- A loop.
- A conditional branching.

If you can think of what the function is doing as a sequence of actions, then use the sequence of statements, i.e. the first method.

If the way you explain what the function does makes you realize that some step is actually part of a greater step, then structure those steps accordingly, one inside the other.

Comment: thx for fast response, could you give me real example "step part of greater step"?

Comment: @gilbertxenodike "Open fridge door", "Put beer inside fridge", "Close fridge door" and "Wait" can be seen as steps part of a greater step "Make Beer Cool".

Comment: Isn't that a sequence? Sorry I'm confuse?

Comment: Yes, yes. But imagine that your _complete_ sequence is "Go to supermarket", "Pick beer", "Pay", "Return home", "Open fridge door", "Put beer inside fridge", "Close fridge door" and "Wait". Then you could identify two "greater actions": "Buy Beer" and "Make Beer Cool". So instead of one big list of eight or nine items, you'd make a list of these two big items, and then inside each of one make the sub-list of smaller actions.